Why are non-Catholics allowed to attend all of mass?
I learned recently the name "mass" comes from the Latin "misa" which means dismissal.  In the early church in Rome, the preparation portion of the mass could be attended by all, but then when it came time to sacrifice the Eucharist, all non-Catholics were dismissed.

To remain until the missa or dismissal of the catechumens, is easily changed into: to remain for, or during, the Missa of the Catechumens.  When the discipline of the catechumens was done away with, and there was only the one connected service, it was called by the long-familiar name, Missa, or Mass.
-- "The Latin Mass Explained", Msgr. George J. Moorman

My question is what changed to allow non-Catholics to now attend the sacrifice portion of the mass?  What were the original concerns that kept them out, and have these concerns been addressed in some way?

Where did you learn that the word mass comes from the dismissal of non-Catholics?

I think you mistake the dismissal of the cathechumens in the middle of the liturgy with the phrase "ite missa est" that the priest said at the end of the liturgy to dismiss the whole congregation, from which the English word "mass" came from. See this explanation.  Other than that, it is a good question.

This question is as ridiculous as it sounds, no one can stand at the door and start asking people if they are Catholic or not because the house of God is open to even non-believers

Why are non-Catholics allowed to attend all of mass?
There is not one reason for, but a number of historical reasons that led to the reason why the Church in her infancy did not permit non-baptized catechumens to be present when the prayers of the Eucharist were being said and then later permitted non-catholic Protestants to attend the mass in whole.
Let us clear up a few concepts first.
First of all the word mass does mean?
Clearly it doe not come from when the Early Church dismisses the non-baptized catechumens from attending the Eucharistic portion of the mass. It actually comes from the the actual dismissal by of the priest at the end of the mass with the words: ”Ite missa est”. Alas, knowing a little Latin is always helpful.

“Mass” is an English rendering of the Latin term “missa.” In Latin the Mass ends with “Ite missa est,” which translated into English means “Go, it is sent,” the “it” being the Church. From the Latin word “missa” comes the English word “dismiss.” So “Mass” means “dismissal.” The celebration takes its name from the sending forth that occurs at the end of every Mass.
“Mass” is derived from the way the Mass was ended in Latin. Because of the familiarity of the ending, the celebration of our Lord’s Supper eventually became known simply as the “Mass.” There were actually two dismissals in the celebration — one in which catechumens (people who were not fully Catholic yet but wanted to be) were dismissed right after the sermon, and the dismissal at the end, when all the fully initiated Catholics, the faithful, were dismissed. There were two “Masses,” namely the Mass of the Catechumens and the Mass of the Faithful. The fact that we call this greatest of Christian prayers the “dismissal” points to the essence of what it means to be a follower of Jesus Christ. Our Lord calls us to Himself and through His saving act invites us to a unity with God the Father through the power of His Holy Spirit. Jesus makes communion with God possible. But following Jesus does not stop with this communion, for once He has united us to Himself, He then sends us forth with a mission (a dismissal). “Go” is one of His final words to His disciples as He ascends into heaven in the Gospel of Matthew’s account. Hence, the way every Mass ends with “go” is at the heart of what we come to the Mass for — to be empowered by God and sent forth again. The “go” that is the very meaning of the word “Mass” receives its meaning from our communion with our Lord Jesus Christ during the Mass. - Where Does the Term “Mass” Come From?

Now to the cores reasons why the Early Church did not permit non-baptized Catholics from attending the whole mass while the post-protestant Reformation Catholic Church permits non-Catholics to attention the entire mass.
The main reasons are due to historical atmosphere of the times in question of these two events. In the Early Church the Church was being heavily persecuted by the local pagan authorities of those times and the Church felt the need to preserve her faith, doctrine and Divine Liturgies from outside forces. The Church in the early times the priest said the mass in slow voice so as not to draw attention from outside forces that the mass was being said.
With the Protest movements of the 16th century, the first Protestants were in majority ex-catholics who already understood(?) what the entire mass really was. Whether or not these Protestants believed in the Real Presence is another question.

The idea for dismissing catechumens is quite ancient. Evidence from the third to fourth centuries comes from both West and East, the Apostolic Tradition and the Apostolic Constitutions. Both are church orders; that is, they contain collections of rubrics and suggestions for governance. The Apostolic Tradition presents an elaborate description of the entire catechumenal process and the rites of initiation. Although the origins of this document are complex and disputed, the Apostolic Tradition is generally thought to preserve the thinking of the Roman Church at a very early stage. Not long ago, the presumed author was Hippolytus; however, scholars now doubt that the man who became both saint and antipope was the same person who collected the work now known as the Apostolic Tradition. The work had been lost for many centuries. Discovered in the mid-nineteenth century, its significance came to light in the early twentieth. By the time of the Second Vatican Council, it became a motherlode of material for ressourcement, the movement to go back to the sources."
By the fifth century, Saint Augustine was practicing dismissals. In Sermon 132, he noted that catechumens could attend the word service with the faithful, but not the eucharist. Because Augustine carries so much authority in the history of the development of doctrine, his liturgical practices were also influential in the post-Vatican II reforms. The practice of the Apostolic Tradition and the Apostolic Constitutions should have provided sufficiently convincing evidence for the restoration of dismissals in the twentieth-century Church. That Augustine also practiced dismissals surely sealed the deal."
Why did the early Church dismiss catechumens? Augustine says in the same sermon that he hoped the practice would make them curious. By not participating in the eucharist, they would naturally wonder what they were missing. This intrigue would keep them returning for instruction so that they could one day be admitted to the rest of the liturgy through the waters of baptism."
Fourth-century Christians probably wanted to protect their privacy. They were subject to much misunderstanding and persecution, difficulties that catechesis would remedy. Consequently, they did not admit the uninitiated into the eucharist, nor did they share the Creed with just anyone. Only those being made ready for baptism were given the Creed, and that was done orally. They did not write it down, for fear it would fall into the hands of the uncatechized, who would misrepresent the nuances of what Christians believed. The body of catechesis came to be known as the disciplina arcani - the learning of the secret."
Furthermore, the faithful who remain for the Liturgy of the Eucharist enter into the part of the mass for which their baptism has prepared them."

The Creed is the first activity that follows the dismissal. Catechumens who have not received the Creed nor professed it in their baptism do not yet own it. But the Creed unifies the baptized, who share a common faith."

The prayer of the faithful (the universal prayer or the bidding prayers)is just that: the prayer that belongs to the baptized faithful. The General Instruction of the Roman Missal explicitly makes this point (69). This prayer is an exercise of the priestly ministry by those who are baptized and anointed as Christ was anointed priest, prophet and king. Just as a priest prays, so do the priestly people. Each time the people answer “Hear us, O Lord,” or some other variation on that response, they are addressing God and praying as the baptized faithful."

The collection is a symbol of the sacrifice that the people a remaking to God in Christ. They believe that the sacrifice of the cross was the perfect act of praise, and they will now unite their own sacrifice with that of Christ. Placing money in the basket is a sacred Christian sacrificial act expressing belief in the power of the cross."

In the eucharistic prayer, the faithful join with the priest in giving praise to God and offering the sacrifice (GIRM 78). Again, they are exercising their baptismal priesthood."

The Lord’s Prayer is the prayer of God’s own children. Many catechumens have already been praying it on their own, but through their baptism they will become children of God in a more profound way, reborn through the waters of life. After their baptism they will join the faithful in praying “Our Father,” as they number themselves among the body of believers."

The sign of peace, as the Apostolic Tradition indicates, is a symbol shared among baptized Christians. It is not a polite expression of greeting, nor a time to exchange messages, nor a brief intermission. Rather, it is a deep indication of the unique bond shared among Christians. The kiss of peace foreshadows the sacrament soon to come."

The sharing of communion is the most profound expression of Christian belief and unity. Only the baptized are invited to share at the table of the Lord’s Body and Blood."

At the dismissal, the faithful aresentforthasabody,nourished with the eucharist, to bring the gospel to the world. Their dismissal is different from that of the catechumens. - Dismissals in the Rite of Christian
Initiation of Adults"



It is abundantly clear the Early Church believed in the Eucharist and she had to protect this doctrine as best as possible from ridicule from Pagan leaders and followers. Certainly many of the early Catechumens were from these ranks.
The followers of Christ have been questioned whether or not Jesus truly gives us his body and blood in the Eucharist since he first told us in John 6:

If any man eat of this bread, he shall live for ever; and the bread that I will give, is my flesh, for the life of the world.
The Jews therefore strove among themselves, saying: How can this man give us his flesh to eat? - John 6:53-55


From this time many of his disciples turned back and no longer followed him.
“You do not want to leave too, do you?” Jesus asked the Twelve.
Simon Peter answered him, “Lord, to whom shall we go? You have the words of eternal life.
We have come to believe and to know that you are the Holy One of God.” - John 6:66-69

Thus we can see the the faithful of the Early Church felt the need to the preserve and protect the Catholic doctrine in a way to avoid more persecution and misrepresentation of what her doctrine were truly all about.
By the time the the Protestant Reformation had come about, many of the first Protestants were indeed Catholics who abandoned their faith in order to be Protestants. Thus the Divine Mysteries of the Mass were well known to them, the Church did not think it was necessary to refuse them the ability of attending mass.
Like all those who abandon their faith in the Catholic Church, Holy Mother Church encourages all ex-catholics to attend mass, but forbids them from from receiving Holy Communion until that time that they are reconciled with the Church through the sacrament of confession.
The successive generations of Protestants may attend mass now since it is obvious that the average Protestant knows what the mass is all about. Nevertheless they too are forbidden to receive the Eucharist until that moment that they are properly catechized as to the real teaching of the Church and are properly educated in Catholic doctrine and make a public profession of faith in the Catholic Church and when necessary receive the sacraments of baptism and\or confirmation.
The Eucharist remains the greatest mystery and treasure of the Catholic Church.
